# Setting COM server launch permissions in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com

I have a COM server where I need to check its launch permissions and optionally add the IUSER to the access list from Delphi code. COM Launch permissions are documented here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687202(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

How do I read or modify the LaunchPermission from code?

Thanks,

/A